'Dangerous Site' warning in Chrome when hosting projects
I'm encountering an issue when trying to host my websites on GitHub Pages. Every time I publish a project, Chrome displays a "Dangerous site" warning, like the one shown in the screenshot below:
(https://i.sstatic.net/7oc1Zv0e.png)
The message suggests that the site could trick users into installing malicious software or revealing sensitive information (passwords, credit card numbers, etc.). However, my site only hosts simple static HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files.
For example, this issue occurred with my Calculator Project, which is a basic JavaScript application. I am sure the code doesn’t have anything malicious.
Here's what I've tried so far:
Ensuring that the code is clean and does not contain any malicious content.
Using HTTPS, which is automatically enabled for GitHub Pages.
Testing in incognito mode, clearing the cache, and trying other browsers. However, Chrome continues to flag the site as dangerous.
Is there a known solution to this issue? Why does GitHub Pages get flagged as dangerous on Chrome, and how can I resolve this so that my users don't encounter this security warning?
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!
enter image description here
Dangerous site
Attackers on the site you're trying to visit might trick you into installing software or revealing things like your password, phone, or credit card number. Chrome strongly recommends going back to safety. Learn more about this warning

I checked some of the other projects of yours too and those also were being flagged by the browser(when standard protection was turned on). I think the issue is related to the pattern in your GitHub username daniyal00001, which is mentioned in your site's URL daniyal00001.github.io, which is causing the browser to flag it and not your code. Moreover, your site, https://daniyal00001.github.io/Calculator-using-Javascript/, is flagged by two of the security vendors on VirusTotal. You can check the results here: VirusTotal Report.
You will have to update your site's domain either by getting a domain or updating the github.io subdomain, you can follow one of the steps below to change your github.io subdomain and remember to avoid repetitive sequences like 0000 in the URL like the one you have currently in the URL (as it is your GitHub username)
1. Change Your GitHub Username: For example, you could use daniyal458 or another unique name that’s available.
OR2. You can follow this Reddit guide for instructions on setting up a URL without your username in the subdomain in case you do not want to update your username.

Step-by-Step Process:
Creating a New GitHub Repository:
Log in to your GitHub account.
Create a new repository and name it as [your_username].github.io (e.g., blabla.github.io).
Adding the Sitemap:
Upload the sitemap file (sitemap.xml) you created in XML format to the newly created repository.
Adding Google Search Console Verification Code:
Get the HTML code needed to verify your [your_username].github.io domain from Google Search Console.
Create a new HTML file (e.g., index.html) and place the code within the  section of the file.
Add the index.html file to your repository as well.
Pushing Changes to GitHub:
After making and saving all changes, commit and push the changes to GitHub.
Waiting for GitHub Pages to Publish:
GitHub will automatically publish your changes, and your site will be accessible within about 1-2 minutes.
Completing the Verification in Google Search Console:
Go back to Google Search Console and complete the verification process.(request a review.)
